# Get 'WARNING, currently unsupported 'tf' filter color option, skipped.' error on import of obj and mtl files

Tags: import, error, obj

I've downloaded an obj file with its corresponding mtl file and tried to import it into Blender 2.9.
I get the following errors from the console:

```
Read prefs: C:\Users\EarlK\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.90\config\userpref.blend
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\python
Info: Deleted 1 object(s)

(  0.0000 sec |   0.0000 sec) Importing OBJ 'C:\\Users\\EarlK\\Documents\\Short\\Boy\\BoyOBJ.obj'...
  (  0.0020 sec |   0.0010 sec) Parsing OBJ file...
    (  0.1117 sec |   0.1087 sec) Done, loading materials and images...
WARNING, currently unsupported 'tf' filter color option, skipped.
WARNING, currently unsupported 'tf' filter color option, skipped.
WARNING, currently unsupported 'tf' filter color option, skipped.
WARNING, currently unsupported 'tf' filter color option, skipped.
WARNING, currently unsupported 'tf' filter color option, skipped.
WARNING, currently unsupported 'tf' filter color option, skipped.
WARNING, currently unsupported 'tf' filter color option, skipped.
WARNING, currently unsupported 'tf' filter color option, skipped.
WARNING, currently unsupported 'tf' filter color option, skipped.
WARNING, currently unsupported 'tf' filter color option, skipped.
WARNING, currently unsupported 'tf' filter color option, skipped.
    (  0.1207 sec |   0.1177 sec) Done, building geometries (verts:9580 faces:9308 materials: 11 smoothgroups:12) ...
    (  0.2199 sec |   0.2169 sec) Done.
  (  0.2229 sec |   0.2219 sec) Finished importing: 'C:\\Users\\EarlK\\Documents\\Short\\Boy\\BoyOBJ.obj'
Progress: 100.00%
```

I've checked for matching names and the correct mtl reference in the obj file.  All good here.
I've searched the web for any answer I could find and still cannot solve this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am a programer.  So if the solution to this is altering the code to the MTL file, then point me in the right direction and I'll figure it out.

Comment: BTW: Thanks Christopher for tidying up my mess.  Being a newbie, I wasn't quite sure how to do that.